# Mariadb SELECT not failing on lock

Tags: mariadb

I’m trying to cause a ‘SELECT’ query to fail if the record it is trying to read is locked.
To simulate it I have added a trigger on UPDATE that sleeps for 20 seconds and then in one thread (Java application) I’m updating a record (oid=53) and in another thread I’m performing the following query:

> “SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1 FOR SELECT * FROM Jobs j WHERE j.oid =53”.

(Note: Since my mariadb server version is 10.2 I cannot use the “SELECT … NOWAIT” option and must use “SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1 FOR ….” instead).

I would expect that the SELECT will fail since the record is in a middle of UPDATE and should be read/write locked, but the SELECT succeeds.
Only if I add ‘for update’ to the SELECT query the query fails. (But this is not a good option for me).
I checked the INNODB_LOCKS table during the this time and it was empty.
In the INNODB_TRX table I saw the transaction with isolation level – REPEATABLE READ, but I don’t know if it is relevant here.
Any thoughts, how can I make the SELECT fail without making it 'for update'?

Comment: Did the `SELECT` execute promptly?  In which case it was unaffected by that particular lock.

Comment: Yes it did. Right. @elenst’s answer explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally consistent (and dirty) reads are non-locking, they just read some sort of snapshot, depending on what your transaction isolation level is. If you want to make the read wait for concurrent transaction to finish, you need to set isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` **and** turn off autocommit in the connection that performs the read. Something like

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET autocommit = 0;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1 FOR ...
```

should do it.

[Relevant page in MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/set-transaction/#serializable)

*Side note: my personal preference would be to use `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1` instead of `max_statement_time=1`. Both will make the statement fail, but `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` will cause an error code more suitable for the situation.*

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the reasonable explanation. I just made a design change that made this approach of using an explicit lock im my application redundant. Thank you very much for the answer and I marked it as accepted.

Comment: @elenst - Why is the setting of `autocommit` important in this context?

Comment: @RickJames - if `autocommit` is enabled, `SELECT` is a single-statement read-only transaction, which even with the serializable level is known not to need to block. It is documented behavior, both for MySQL and MariaDB.